# How to add options check menu to CMFCToolBar to allow multiple checks at time

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, popupmenubutton, cmfctoolbar

I want to add a menu button to a CMFCToolbar that allow checking multiple options at a time, when I add a menu and check an item on click the menu is closed I need a menu like the menu in the customization button as in the following image
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want the menu to remain active (visible) after you've made a selection.  Is that correct?

Comment: @rrirower : yes that is what I want. to stay active after selection

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you look for a different design.  What you're proposing is non-standard behavior.  Menus don't usually act that way.  Second, how would the menu close when the selections are complete?  Now, having said that, if you feel you need to pursue that design, I would recommend you look to handle **CMFCToolBarMenuButton::OpenPopupMenu** and derive your own menu from CMFCPopupMenu.  A CMFCPopupMenu is actually a mini frame window at the lower level.  You should be able to provide the behavior you want within your derived popup menu class.